# Как усмирить отступы при взаимодействии с шириной?

Tags: css, width

Итак, при нажатии на айтем появляется скрытый контент посредством выкручивания ширины контейнера с 0 до 100, при возвращении наоборот - с 100 до 0, и видно как по мере уменьшения ширины весь контент также сползает, это еще связано и с классом `.container` который родом из бутстрапа, есть какая-то хитрость чтобы не дать контенту зарости сотнями новых строчек и как-то его зафиксировать при возвращении ширины в 0?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/poNjrrq)

P.S. Если я не сильно хорошо объяснил суть проблемы измените скорость анимации с 0.6s на пару секунд

```css
.fsmenu {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.fsmenu .fsmenu--container {
  width: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 60px;
//  padding: 8em 3em 3em;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fsmenu.is-active {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
.fsmenu.is-active .fsmenu--container {
  -webkit-animation: animMenuReveal 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.13, 0.02, 1.07) 0s forwards;
          animation: animMenuReveal 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.13, 0.02, 1.07) 0s forwards;
}
.fsmenu.close-menu {
    display: block;
  -webkit-animation: hideDisplay 0.6s forwards;
          animation: hideDisplay 0.6s forwards;
}
.fsmenu.close-menu .fsmenu--container {
  width: 100vw;
//  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: animMenuClose 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.13, 0.02, 1.07) 0.3s forwards;
          animation: animMenuClose 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.13, 0.02, 1.07) 0.3s forwards;
}

.content__back {
    background: url('../img/arrow_left.svg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideDisplay {
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hideDisplay {
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animMenuReveal {
  0% {
    width: 0vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}

@keyframes animMenuReveal {
  0% {
    width: 0vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animMenuClose {
  0% {
    width: 100vw;
//    padding: 8em 3em 3em;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0vw;
//    padding: 8em 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animMenuClose {
  0% {
    width: 100vw;
//    padding: 8em 3em 3em;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0vw;
//    padding: 8em 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз вы знаем, что ширина всегда будет равна ширине экрана, почему не использовать обёртку для контента с фиксированной шириной (`100vw`), у которой не будет "деформации" при изменение размера родителя?

Вот типо такого:

```js
let anim = $('.block-anim');

$('.btn-open, .btn-close').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('btn-open')) {
    anim.animate({'width': '100%'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      anim.css({'left': 0, 'right': ''});
    });
  } else {
    anim.animate({'width': '0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      anim.css({'right': 0, 'left': ''});
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-open,
.btn-close {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-open {border: 1px solid black;}
.btn-close {border: 1px solid white;}

.block-anim {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9990;
}

.block-anim .fix-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-open">Open</div>

<div class="block-anim">
  <div class="fix-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-close">Close</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Сижу за решеткой в темнице сырой.<br>
        Вскормленный в неволе орел молодой,<br>
        Мой грустный товарищ, махая крылом,<br>
        Кровавую пищу клюет под окном,
      </p>
      <p>
        Клюет, и бросает, и смотрит в окно,<br>
        Как будто со мною задумал одно.<br>
        Зовет меня взглядом и криком своим<br>
        И вымолвить хочет: «Давай улетим!
      </p>
      <p>
        Мы вольные птицы; пора, брат, пора!<br>
        Туда, где за тучей белеет гора,<br>
        Туда, где синеют морские края,<br>
        Туда, где гуляем лишь ветер… да я!…»
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```